# Nuxt authenticate Middleware doesn't work when click back button from browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm implementing the protected route in nuxt the best way I found is using the middleware, so I implemented it with the using of module **cookie-universal-nuxt**.

Everything is working smoothly, but when user session is expire and I click on any protected route its navigating me to the login page which is what I want the only bug is that when I click on the back button on the browser (browser default back button) it shows again the protected page while the user session is already expire.

setting the cookies and in localstroage and cookies.

```
const expireAt = Helpers.getJwtData().exp * 1000
window.localStorage.setItem('tokenExpire',expireAt);
this.$cookies.set('tokenExpire', expireAt, { path: '/'})
```

**middleware/autheticate.js**

```
export default function (context) {
  const expiry = context.$cookies?.get('tokenExpire');
  const isLoggedIn = +expiry > new Date().getTime
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    Helpers.logout();
    context.redirect(`/login?redirect_path=${context.route.path}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: the previous page is getting cached locally and will show, if you refresh or do any operation it'll take you to the login page again.

Comment: If you are using the keep-alive option i suggest that you exclude all the pages or components that require auth. Like this they won't be cached.

Another way would be to use the `activated` hook and recheck there the token